# WinSCP IDisposable Wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, wrapper

I have written a simple wrapper for WinSCP in C#. I have written it to simplify SFTP connections I will needing to perform.

```
public class WinSCPConn : IDisposable
{
        //private fields
        private SessionOptions sessionOptions;
        private TransferOptions transferOptions;
        private Session session;

        //public properties
        public bool IsSessionOpen { get { return session.Opened; } }

        public WinSCPConn(string hostname, string username, string password)
        {
            sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
            sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol.Sftp;
            sessionOptions.HostName = hostname;
            sessionOptions.PortNumber = 22;
            sessionOptions.Password = password;
            sessionOptions.UserName = username;
            sessionOptions.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
            sessionOptions.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true;

            transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

            try
            {
                session = new Session();
                session.ExecutablePath = Properties.Settings.Default.WinSCPPath;
            }
            catch (SessionLocalException)
            {
                throw;
            } 

        }

        public void Open()
        {
            try
            {
                if (session.Opened == false)
                {
                    session.Open(sessionOptions);
                }
            }
            catch (SessionRemoteException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public TransferOperationResult SendFile(string SourceFile, string DestFile)
        {
            TransferOperationResult result;
            try
            {
                 result = session.PutFiles(SourceFile, DestFile, false, transferOptions);
                 return result;
            }
            catch (SessionRemoteException)
            {
                 throw;
            }  
        }

        public void CreateDirectory(string FolderPath)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!session.FileExists(FolderPath))
                {
                    session.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
                }
            }
            catch (SessionRemoteException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (session.Opened == true)
            {
                session.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Close();
        }
 }
```

It would be used as follows:

```
 using (WinSCPConn conn = new WinSCPConn("host", "username", "password"))
 {                       
      conn.Open();
      conn.CreateDirectory("/path/");
      conn.SendFile(@"C:\file.txt","/path/file.txt");
 }
```

My questions are as follows:

1. How is my exception handling?
2. Is there too much going on in the constructor?

Comment: Error handling ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Timeout

```
sessionOptions.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
```

Instead of using the TimeSpan constructor, I would instead use the TimeSpan.FromX methods.  In this case, it would be [`TimeSpan.FromMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
sessionOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
```

It is a little more obvious that the timeout is 3 minutes now.

### Port

```
sessionOptions.PortNumber = 22;
```

For this, I see two options:

- Take port as a parameter
- Omit the line

If you are *always* using the default port, you can omit the assignment.  According to the [WinSCP API Doc](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions), leaving the port to the default of 0 will cause it to use the protocol default (22 for SFTP).

Keep in mind that always is not *always* always :)

### Session Creation

```
try
{
    session = new Session();
    session.ExecutablePath = Properties.Settings.Default.WinSCPPath;
}
catch (SessionLocalException)
{
    throw;
}
```

This part actually has two problems with it:

- the catch does not do anything aside from re-throw the exception
- you are throwing an exception in the constructor of an `IDisposable` type, which breaks using statements

For the first point, you could just remove the try/catch.  It only has a purpose if you are planning on doing something in the catch.  This is true for all of your try/catch blocks.

The next point could be solved with lazy initialization of the session.  If you change the if statement within `Open` to do a null check, you can create and open the session there.

```
public void Open()
{
    if (session == null)
    {
        session = new Session();
        session.ExecutablePath = Properties.Settings.Default.WinSCPPath;
        session.Open(sessionOptions);
    }
}
```

Perhaps more robust, though, is just to add a separate if check and do the creation/opening separately:

```
public void Open()
{
    if (session == null)
    {
        session = new Session();
        session.ExecutablePath = Properties.Settings.Default.WinSCPPath;
    }
    if (session.Opened == false)
    {
        session.Open(sessionOptions);
    }
}
```

### IDisposable

There are a couple things you may want to address with your `IDispoable` implementation:

- suppress finalization
- support cases where `Dispose` is never called
- allow sub-classes to override disposal behavior or seal the class

The first one is pretty easy:

```
public void Dispose()
{
   Close();
   GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

The second one depends largely on how the WinSCP `Session` class is written.  You may need to ensure that the session is closed even if `Dispose` is never called, though you only need to worry about actually disposing of it when `Dispose` *is* called.

For the last one, I would just mark the class as `sealed`, since you have neither `virtual` nor `protected` members.  Otherwise, you should provide a virtual `Dispose` method.  Generally, when doing so, your empty `Dispose` remains non-virtual, and you would provide an additional protected overload which takes in a boolean.

For more information, see:
Code analysis rule [CA1063](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx) and the MSDN page on [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

- a condition to be met like `if (someBoolean == true)` can be simplified to `if (someBoolean)`. For reverse check use the Not operator `!` like `if (!someBoolean)`.
- `Dipsose()` should not only call `Close()` but also get rid of `session`, `sessionOptions` and `transferOptions` by calling `Dispose()` if they implement `IDisposible` or at least setting them to `null`.
- `SendFile()`

  you should declare the variable as near as possible to its usage and instead of catching .. rethrowing the exception, let it bubble up the tree. So it can be simplified to

  ```
  public TransferOperationResult SendFile(string SourceFile, string DestFile)
  {
      return session.PutFiles(SourceFile, DestFile, false, transferOptions);
  }
  ```
- if comments don't add any value, like explaining **why** something is done (**what** is done should be explained by the code itself), they should be removed like

  ```
  //public properties
  ```

Answer (score 3):

1. Is there a reason you're catching some exceptions and just re-throwing them? It doesn't appear that you're really doing anything. In this case, you might as well not even catch the exception and just let it propagate up naturally. If the API threw a lot of different exceptions you'd like to catch, in that case you might want to re-wrap them in your wrapper class to make them easier to catch for your calling classes.
2. I don't think so - the length of code looks reasonable and it's readable.

Comment: no reason, i was just catching and throwing!

Comment: Removing the redundant `try... catch { throw; }` statements will simplify your code. Like @RubberDuck mentioned below, if you want to test your class, it may be better to pass the Option classes in (dependency injection). I think testing needs to be discretionary though; you are simply wrapping a pre-existing 3rd party API in this case, so in my opinion I don't think it's absolutely necessary. As always, YMMV depending on your needs though.